# SQL Server: cursor only returns records first time when running in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-cursor

I'm hoping someone can help with this! I'm trying to write a stored procedure that uses a cursor. When I test this in Management Studio, the sproc only returns records the first time it's run. If I copy/past to another query window, it again returns records only the first time. When run from C#, the sproc works as expected.

The query below demonstrates the problem. Thanks in advance!

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Query to reproduce problem with using cursor - management studio
-------------------------------------------------------------------
--
Declare     crsrTest Cursor For 
Select      TABLE_NAME 
From        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES; 

Declare     @TableName  varchar(128);
Open        crsrTest;  

-- 
-- This will only return records the *first* time when running in MS. 
-- Every time after that, I get the 'No records' message. 
-- 
if @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 
    Print 'No records';             
while   @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 begin 
    Fetch   Next 
    From    crsrTest
    Into    @TableName;  
    Print   @TableName;
end;

Close       crsrTest; 
Deallocate  crsrTest;
```

Comment: `@@FETCH_STATUS` is updated only after `FETCH`, and not reset afterwards. Use a loop of the form `WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN; FETCH ...; IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 BREAK; ... END;` (Repeating the statement is also possible, but I don't like repeating myself.)

Comment: What you might consider is not using a cursor in the first place. Not sure what your real code is doing but row by agonizing row processing can usually be avoided.

Comment: Ugh - I knew someone would tell me not to use a cursor. I already knew this. I know they can *usually* be avoided. That wasn't my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `FETCH NEXT` between the `OPEN` and `IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0`:

```
DECLARE crsrTest CURSOR FOR
     SELECT TABLE_NAME 
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES; 

DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(128);

OPEN crsrTest;  

FETCH NEXT FROM crsrTest INTO @TableName;
PRINT @TableName;

-- This will always return records
IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 
   PRINT 'No records';             

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM crsrTest INTO @TableName;
    PRINT @TableName;
END;

CLOSE crsrTest; 
DEALLOCATE crsrTest;
```

Stay away from cursors if you can (you seem to be new at them, that's why I'm telling). If you're an ORACLE guy, this is not as fast as iterations in PL/SQL.

Comment: Seriously, it's not hard to figure it out. I added the missing PRINT statement.

Comment: It could be easily fixed by switching FETCH and PRINT places inside WHILE. And would look much cleaner.

Comment: I don't use cursors, except for rare one-time transformation where I want to be able to isolate each step and be able to test them individually. I am merely fixing his CURSOR, which is the scope of the question and, as they should, people advise to avoid cursors at all cost.

Comment: Silly me thanks. Yes I know not to use cursors if you can avoid them.

Comment: I really appreciate the feedback! For the record it's almost always better to NOT use a cursor but...in *this* case I'm joining a table with a few records to a function that accepts a parameter based on one of the columns from the first table. You can't actually use a join in this case - you must use a cross apply. For my particular application, the cross apply takes 15 seconds. Using a cursor to iterate the handful of records from the first table and calling the function in the loop runs in 1 second. Same results. "It doesn't matter what the textbook says, it matters what the computer does."

Comment: Cursors have their use. But always avoid them if you can.